# Decouple nomencl from chapter class, to have its own formatting

Tags: xetex, formatting, chapters, nomenclature

I'm using the `nomencl` package to keep track of my abbreviations in my `\documentclass{report}`, where I am using `xelatex` to change the font. However, since I've made changes to the way `\chapter{}` is printed, it also affects the nomenclature heading.

This is how my chapter looks, after my changes, e.g. it includes a different font size, right-justified/ragged left, a different text color, and a bottom `\hrule`:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Large}
{
\hfill\fontsize{80}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}\thechapter}
{-2ex}
{\filleft\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}}
[\vspace{0ex}\hrule]
```

This code makes the `\chapter{Introduction}` look like this:
[image]

However, due to the changes, my nomenclature heading (which I've renamed to Abbreviations, see code below) looks like this:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\vspace{-3.8cm}\begin{flushleft}
\fontsize{30}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont Abbreviations\end{flushleft}\vspace{-3.8cm}}
```

[image]

As you can see, the `\hrule` is kinda floating around (in my MWE, it is placed above, in my full preamble, it goes straight through the word - probably due to some other parameters, font sizes etc., but if I can figure it out for my MWE, I can probably fix my full preamble as well).

So, my question is, of course, how I can either get rid of the line from Abbreviations or move it down, so it matches the line in the chapters. Whatever is easiest. My own idea is, if I in some way can make xelatex avoid interpret the nomenclature as a chapter, but as plain text (but keep the font/font size).

This is my full MWE (note I'm using some unusual fonts, feel free to change it, and maybe there are some unnecessary commands as well, but this reproduces my problem):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{report} 

\usepackage[math-style=TeX,bold-style=TeX,partial=literal,vargreek-shape=TeX]{unicode-math} %Also loads {fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional},SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=0},
             BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold},BoldFeatures={LetterSpace=3}]{Minion Pro}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont{Neo Sans Std Light}
\newfontfamily\normalfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nomencl}
    \makenomenclature
    \makeindex

\definecolor{dtured}{RGB}{153,0,0}

%Formats the chapter:
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Large}
{
\hfill\fontsize{80}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}\thechapter}
{-2ex}
{\filleft\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}}
[\vspace{0ex}\hrule] %HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC \HRULE

%renews the command \nomenclature{}{}, AND changes the name to "Abbreviations"
\newcommand*{\nom}[2]{#1\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\vspace{-3.8cm}\begin{flushleft}
    \fontsize{30}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont Abbreviations\end{flushleft}\vspace{-3.8cm}}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature[2cm]
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
The mass (\nom{m}{Mass}) is heavy.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for `\printnomenclature` is to issue

```
\chapter*{\nomname}
```

so you just have to redefine the name:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
```

and you get

[image]

The font is different, because I don't have the one you're using, but this is irrelevant for the problem.

Note: it's definitely a ***very bad idea*** to do

```
\newfontfamily\normalfont{Minion Pro}
```

Just remove it.

---

Here's an improved version, where the chapter title is at the same vertical level both in the numbered and in the unnumbered case. I made some other improvements, in particular changed `\hrule` into `\titlerule`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{report} 

\usepackage[
  math-style=TeX,
  bold-style=TeX,
  partial=literal,
  vargreek-shape=TeX
]{unicode-math} %Also loads {fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[
  Numbers={Proportional},
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=0},
  BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold},
  BoldFeatures={LetterSpace=3}
]{Minion Pro}
%\setsansfont{Neo Sans Std Light}    % <------- UNCOMMENT THIS!
\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\sffamily}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\makeindex

\definecolor{dtured}{RGB}{153,0,0}

%Formats the chapter:
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} % it's so by default
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
  {\Large}
  {\hfill\fontsize{80}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}\thechapter}
  {-2ex}
  {\filleft\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}}
  [\vspace{0ex}\titlerule]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Large}
  {\hfill\fontsize{80}{50}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}\vphantom{\thechapter}}
  {-2ex}
  {\filleft\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}}
  [\vspace{0ex}\titlerule]

%renews the command \nomenclature{}{}, AND changes the name to "Abbreviations"
\newcommand*{\nom}[2]{#1\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[2cm]

\chapter{Introduction}
The mass (\nom{m}{Mass}) is heavy.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's some awesome solutions! Thanks a lot! Is it equally easy to do this formatting to the "Contents"? I mean, using \titleformat? So that both Abbreviations, Contents, and Introduction look the same (but only Introduction has a number, and is visible in the contents? I know this is not my original question, so if it's not so easy, never mind.

Comment: @NielsMøller Every chapter title using `\chapter*` will be formatted the same way.

Comment: I see, but I just use \tableofcontents to create the toc, but so far, I've been using the following to change the size, color and font of the word "Contents" in toc, but I cannot think of a way to include `\titlerule`: `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont\chapterfont\color{dtured}}`

Comment: @NielsMøller Do `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, otherwise you get into problems. You probably don't have the `titles` option.

Comment: That's awesome! No, I didn't, everything is perfect now. Thanks for your answers!